# How do you get data to plot in SQLDeveloper Report Charting in a Split Dual Y Chart?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to use the Reporting capability in SQL Developer.  I can get the charting to work fine except with a split dual-Y chart.  How do I write the query and configure the report to get data to plot on both of the charts?  Right now I have a query with the series, X value, Y1 Value, and Y2 value, but only the Y1 value plots.  I added what I believe is the second value in the "Data" pane by having two rows in the "Mapping" section.  Any help is appreciated.

[image: SQLDeveloper Report - Dual Split Y]

Comment: haven't looked at that chart type before, but you have the same series for both, is that right?

Comment: That was it...I needed a separate column in the query with a different series.  Basically, select series1, series 2, x_val, yval1, yval2...group by series1,series2, x_val